Discard comments and whitespace while reading from a file in sh
I need to make a piece of code that is too difficult for my current skill
This must be in sh because the rest of the script is in sh, and I run it on freebsd just so you know, because I think there might be some differences between awk on linux and freebsd
I have an external file like this
some "data1"  #some comment
some data2  #some comment
some "data3"  #some comment
some "data4"
some data5 #maybe some comment

and I need to concatenate it into string like this (skipping comments)
(some "data1") or (some data2) or (some "data3") or (some "data4") or (some data5)

I need to skip everything after # and also the last "or" is skipped, can someone help me doing this in sh, thank you :)
I could probably do it myself, but i have no clue how to skip the comments

If your data can contain quoted #, sh is probably not up to the task.

You can trim both prefixes and suffixes with parameter expansion -- see BashFAQ #73 (though sh only promises a subset of the PE forms supported by bash, they're sufficient for the purpose at hand).
#!/bin/sh

output=""
while IFS= read -r line; do
  while :; do
    case $line in
      *"#"*)        line=${line%%"#"*};;       # remove comment
      *[[:space:]]) line=${line%[[:space:]]};; # remove trailing whitespace
      *)            break;;                    # nothing left to remove
    esac
  done
  output="${output} or ($line)"
done
output=${output# or } # remove the first " or "

echo "$output"

See this running, with your desired output, at https://ideone.com/mqnH18

oh wow I was expecting a simple oneliner, not a surprise I could not do it myself, let me test it

I tried substituting your while IFS with
cat zzz.list | while read line; do
but it does not work, the final output is empty, I Played around with it, inside the loop output variable has a proper value but at the end it is empty, pretty strange

cat zzz.list | while read line; d that is not going to work, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

@Stefan, put <zzz.list after the done (on the same line) if you want the loop to read from a file. Read the link in KamilCuk's comment to understand why the pipe doesn't work.

Also tangentially useless use of cat

It could be a one-liner in sed or Awk but you specifically asked for a sh solution.


Remove all comments
Add ( ... ) to each line
join lines by or


sed 's/ *#.*//; s/.*/( & )/' external_file | sed -z 's/\n\(.\)/ or \1/g'

or like:
sed 's/ *#.*//; s/.*/( & ) or /' external_file | paste -sd '' | sed 's/ or $//'

or:
sed 's/ *#.*//; s/.*/( & )/; $!s/$/ or/' | paste -sd ' '

but with GNU sed:
sed -z 's/\([^\n]*[^ ]\) *#[^\n]*\n/( \1 ) or /g; s/ or $/\n/' external_file

But the idea stays the same.

sed -z does not work on my os

You alluded to Awk, so here's an Awk attempt.
awk '{ printf("%s(%s %s)", sep, $1, $2)
    sep=" or " }
  END { printf("\n") }' file

This can be quite simple because Awk already tokenizes the input, so the first two tokens on each line are $1 and $2. For this to work correctly, there must always be whitespace before the text you want to trim (though you could perhaps tweak the input field separator with -F to adjust that).
The shell's read command has a somewhat similar feature, so you could say
sep=""
while read -r first second rest; do
    printf "%s(%s %s)" "$sep" "$first" "$second"
    sep=" or "
done <file
printf "\n"


Using any POSIX awk even if you have white space in your data1, etc. strings (if you have #s then you need to include that in your example):
$ awk '{sub(/#.*/,""); sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,""); printf "%s(%s)", sep, $0; sep=" or "} END{print ""}' file
(some "data1") or (some data2) or (some "data3") or (some "data4") or (some data5)


perl -ne'
   s/\s*(?:\#.*)?\n\z/;
   print $. == 1 ? "($_)" : " or ($_)";
   END { print "\n"; }
'

perl -ne'
   s/\s*(?:\#.*)?\n\z/;
   print "$p($_)";
   $p = " or ";
   END { print "\n"; }
'

perl -ne'
   printf "%s(%s)", $p, s/\s*(?:\#.*)?\n\z/r;
   END { print "\n"; }
'

Note: Like the other solutions presented, these treat the first # as the start of a comment, even if it's quotes.
